regex, how to extract a string between two words
string text = "0. Index - 1, Name - mirlan, Balance - 300";

i need to extract integer 1 as index, string "mirlan" as name, int balance as 300
i need to do it with regex, regular expressions
1st attempt:
Regex regexIndex = new Regex(@"Index-[0-9]*,", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
int index = Convert.ToInt32(regexIndex.Match(text));

2nd attempt:
Regex regexIndex = new Regex(@"Index-[0-9]*,", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
MatchCollection IndexMatches = regexIndex.Matches(text);
int index = Convert.ToInt32(IndexMatches[0].Value);


I think you misunderstood: IgnorePatternWhitespace ignores the whitespace in your regular expression, not the string you're searching. You're nearly there, you just need to add some \s in the regular expression.

(\d+(?=,)).*?(\w+(?=,)).*?(\d+(?=$))


I need to extract integer 1 as index, string "mirlan" as name, int balance as 300

You can use capture groups to extract the values you need.
Example:
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string text = "0. Index - 1, Name - mirlan, Balance - 300";

string pattern = @"Index - (\d+), Name - (.+), Balance - (\d+)";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

int index = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
string name = match.Groups[2].Value;
int balance = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[3].Value);

Console.WriteLine($"Index: {index}");
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}");
Console.WriteLine($"Balance: {balance}");

Output:
Index: 1
Name: mirlan
Balance: 300

PS: Consider replacing spaces with \s* or \s+ if the amount of whitespace between - might change (no whitespace, or more than one space chars).
See Match.Groups Property for more details.

Downvoter care to explain the downvote?
